# How to display text and button in gtk in single window?

Tags: c, user-interface, gtk, gnome

i want to display text on my window and a "next" button  ,but when i am running code it is giving me error.

with next button i want to move to next window where i am displaying something else.
can somebody also tell me how to do this.

```
(try:1914): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkVBox to a GtkWindow, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkWindow can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel
```

my code is:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

        GtkWidget *window;
        GtkWidget *next;

        GtkWidget *label;
        GtkWidget *vbox;
        GtkWidget *hbox;
        GtkWidget *halign;
        GtkWidget *valign;


        gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

        window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
        gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Center");//title position
        gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),600,500);//size
        gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);//position
        label = gtk_label_new("Cold was my soul\n\
                        Untold was the pain\n\
                        I faced when you left me\n\
                        A rose in the rain....\n\
                        So I swore to the razor\n\
                        That never, enchained\n\
                        Would your dark nails of faith\n\
                        Be pushed through my veins again\n\
                        \n\
                        Bared on your tomb\n\
                        I'm a prayer for your loneliness\n\
                        And would you ever soon\n\
                        Come above onto me?\n\
                        For once upon a time\n\
                        On the binds of your lowliness\n\
                        I could always find the slot for your sacred key ");

 gtk_label_set_justify(GTK_LABEL(label), GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);
        vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 5);

        valign = gtk_alignment_new(0, 1, 0, 0);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(vbox), valign);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), vbox);

        hbox = gtk_hbox_new(TRUE, 3);

        next = gtk_button_new_with_label("Next");
        gtk_widget_set_size_request(next, 70, 30);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hbox), next);
        //      close = gtk_button_new_with_label("Close");
        //      gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(hbox), close);

        halign = gtk_alignment_new(1, 0, 0, 0);
        gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(halign), hbox);

        gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(vbox), halign, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
        g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(next), "clicked",
                        G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), G_OBJECT(window));

        gtk_widget_show_all(window);

        g_signal_connect_swapped(G_OBJECT(window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);


        gtk_main ();

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is pretty clear: A `GtkWindow` can contain only one child widget but you have filled it already with the label. To achieve what you want, you have to add `vbox` (that is able to contain several widgets) to the window and then `label` to `vbox`.